# Xcode 4 building but not running OpenFrameworks example apps

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I just installed Xcode 4 (on Mac OS 10.8) and downloaded OpenFrameworks (OF) library and examples. I put Openframeworks files in a random place, and when I open OF examples apps and try to build & run them with Xcode, it tells me "Building succeeded" but it's not actually running the application. I'm not a developer and I have no idea what to do!

Comment: Ok, i found this answer and it seems to work: http://danielmclaren.com/node/188

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that link spells it out, but to put it here:

The problem is that you haven't selected an application in your build settings for that scheme. So to do this:

1. Click on the name of the scheme (it's next to the "stop" button in the top left corner, and probably says "emptyExample Debug" or "emptyExample Release".
2. Click on "Edit Scheme..."
3. A window will appear. Select "Run" from the bar on the left.
4. Select "Info" from the options along the top of the window.
5. From the dropdown menu next to "Executable", select "emptyExample.app"

Now your OF application should build as expected.